# Best way to update Cache:Google Guava

Tags: java, caching, thread-safety, guava

this is my what I am doing

```
Cache<String,MYClass> cache=CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
                maximumSize(100).
                expireAfterAccess(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).
                build();

String id="myid";
MyClass obj=cache.getIfPresent(id);
System.out.println(obj.getMyVariable);
obj.setMyVariable("myNewString");
updateCache(id,obj);
myClass obj2=cache.getIfPresent(id);
System.out.println(obj2.getMyVariable);
```

Does the cache update the MyClass object itself?I guess no.
If not,Which is a better way?

```
void update(String id,MyClass obj){
    cache.put(id,obj);
}
```

or

```
void update(String id,Myclass obj){
     cache.invalidate(id);
     cache.put(id,obj);
}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
myOldString
myNewString
```

Comment: Guava's `Cache` _does not_ copy objects put in it. If you're modifying an object obtained from the cache, you're modifying it _for everyone_ (and there's no need to update the cache for that). It's better to cache objects that are immutable, or at least properly support concurrent modifications.

Answer (score 6):

Guava's `Cache` *does not* copy objects put in it. If you're modifying an object obtained from the cache, you're modifying it *for everyone* (and there's no need to update the cache for that, since it references the same instance).

It's better to cache objects that are immutable, or at least properly support concurrent modifications (and that doesn't usually mean that its accessors are simply `synchronized`, so it's easier said than done).